# Difference in protocol implementation behavior based on type declaration

Tags: swift

Based on whether the type is explicitly declared or inferred the below code gives different outputs.

1. Why does it behave this way. Why can't I implement myFloat in my class if I declare the type?
2. What do I need to do if i want to declare the type explicitly but also override the implementation in the extension so that the call to testClass1.myFloat() returns 2.7?

This with Xcode 8.1, Swift 2.3

```
import UIKit

protocol TestSource {
  func myFloat() -> Float
}

extension TestSource {
  func myFloat() -> Float {
    return 2.5
  }
}

protocol TestProtocol: TestSource {

}

class DevClass: TestProtocol {

}

class TestClass: DevClass {
  func myFloat() -> Float {
    return 2.7
  }
}



let testClass1: TestProtocol = TestClass()
testClass1.myFloat() // Returns 2.5

let testClass2 = TestClass()
testClass2.myFloat() // Returns 2.7
```

Comment: You've explicitly declared the type as `TestProtocol`, whose `myFloat` returns 2.5. If you explicitly declare the type as `TestClass`, you'll get 2.7. The whole point of declaring as a type other than the class of the constructor is to get behavior belonging to superclasses or protocols of the class.

Comment: This is a compiler bug, I remember seeing a very similar question here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. The short answer is that protocol extensions to not introduce dynamic dispatch. For a more thorough explanation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431753/swift-protocol-extensions-overriding#answer-31432610). The explanation there is quite thorough and contains an example.

Here is a blog post that dives even more deeply: https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/the-ghost-of-swift-bugs-future

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the answer. Upvoted at both places and marked this question as duplicate.