# Can't override UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
extension FormViewController : UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath?
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
}

extension FormViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    public func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String?
}

class NotifiableFormViewController: FormViewController
```

Why can't I implement and override the DataSource and TableViewDelegate? Error:"Method does not override any of it's superclass method"

```
class FriendsTableViewController: NotifiableFormViewController{
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section \(section)"
    }
}
```

Comment: May be this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31432610/656600

Comment: I need leave it in extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding methods in Swift extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions)

Answer (score 2):

more simply, remove the word `override` because you're not overriding the method, you are implementing it

Answer (score 0):

By definition, extensions can only add functionality to existing classes. It can not change, that includes overriding, the existing implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`are just protocol
If you want override it, you implement above functions in `NotifiableFormViewController`

then override in your `FriendsTableViewController`

but if not implement in your super class, then you can't override it (nothing override implemented delegate or datasource function)