# Override non-dynamic class delaration

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode8, declaration

With new Xcode 8.3, I get the error:

> Cannot override a non-dynamic class declaration from an extension

from the line of code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

How I can avoid this warning?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869177/cant-override-uitableviewdatasource-and-uitableviewdelegate

Comment: You avoid the warning by not overriding in an extension – do the override in the main body of the class. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/38213286/2976878

Answer (score 18):

Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they *cannot override existing functionality.*

You have two options:

1. Move your method inside the Class-scope, instead of extension.
2. Add `dynamic` type to your method (where it's defined), like example.

### Example:

```swift
@objc open dynamic func onLog(_ message: String) -> Void {
    print("Info: \(message)");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

which means, you can't not override like super class delegate method in extension.
the way you can do is mv extension override method to subclass declare.

```
final class DEMO, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { 

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
         return sectionHeader
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
         return 40
    }

}
```