# Access property on generic

Tags: swift, generics

In my app I'm using a CRUD class that enables me to do database operations with generics. The `create`function looks like this:

```
func create<T: Storable>(_ object: T.Type, completion: ((T) -> ())?)
```

This allows me to do the following:

```
database.create(Restaurant.self, completion: nil)
```

Now, the `Storable` protocol has a property called `primaryKey`. However, when I try to access that inside the create function, it always passes me the default.

```
protocol Storable {

}
extension Storable {
    static var primaryKey: String {
        get {
            return "Storable"
        }
    }
}

class Restaurant: Storable {
    override public class var primaryKey: String {
        return "uuid"
    }
}

...

class Database {
    public func create<T: Storable>(_ object: T.Type, completion: ((T) -> ())?) {
        print("Primary key: ", object.primaryKey)
        print("T: ", type(of: T.init()))
    }
 }
```

The above will print the following:

```
Primary key: Storable
T:  Storable
```

Obviously, the primary key should be "uuid". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431753/swift-protocol-extensions-overriding

Answer (score 4):

Add your property as a requirement in the protocol declaration.

```
protocol Storable {
    static var primaryKey: String {get}
}
extension Storable {
    static var primaryKey: String {
        get {
            return "Storable"
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you have no polymorphism (as you’ve observed).